# How can I instruct hbm2ddl to generate sql for MyISAM engine

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hbm2ddl

When I use hbm2ddl commands to auto generate SQL from JPA2 based annotations it automatically creates the table for ENGINE=InnoDB

```
e.g.
create table foo (id integer not null, bar integer) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

What should I do to my JPA model class to generate SQL for ENGINE=MyISAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 3 Dialect in Hibernate for MySQL.

```
MySQL org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
MySQL with InnoDB org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect 
MySQL with MyISAM org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect
```

I guess that would serve the purpose for you.

Please ask if there is anything else you want or if you find any difficulty in implementing it.